# Input tables as rows instead columns

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a way to read a table as rows instead of columns? Like the MWE example below illustrates:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{line123.dat}
    x1  y1  y2      x3      y3
    0   1   2       2       1
    1   2   5       4.1     2
    2   3   5       6.1     3
    4   5   3       8.1     5
    7   9   1       10.1    9
\end{filecontents*}
% I prefer my format to be as follows:
% \begin{filecontents*}{transposed_line123.dat}
%     x1 0 1 2 4 7
%     y1 1 2 3 5 9
%     y2 2 5 5 3 1
%     x3 2 4.1 6.1 8.1 10.1
%     y3 1 2 3 5 9
% \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [x=x1, y=y1] {line123.dat};
        \addplot table [x=x1, y=y2] {line123.dat};
        \addplot table [x=x3, y=y3] {line123.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The reason is because I have more columns that rows in `line123.dat`.

Comment: Hi, Have you forgotten the`\documentclass` that you have used into the your preamble.

Comment: I don't believe I have. It's right after the `filecontents*` environments.

Comment: @Sebastiano Look carefully at the MWE, the `\documentclass` is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\pgfplotstabletranspose`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{transposed_line123.dat}
     x1 0 1 2 4 7
     y1 1 2 3 5 9
     y2 2 5 5 3 1
     x3 2 4.1 6.1 8.1 10.1
     y3 1 2 3 5 9
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} 

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletranspose[input colnames to={x1},colnames from={x1}]{\mytabletoplot}{transposed_line123.dat}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [x=x1, y=y1] {\mytabletoplot};
        \addplot table [x=x1, y=y2] {\mytabletoplot};
        \addplot table [x=x3, y=y3] {\mytabletoplot};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also found out that there is no need to load the "untransposed" table. `\pgfplotstabletranspose` can take the filename as the last input.

Comment: @Tohiko You're right, I'll correct, thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: Mmm.. For some reason when the data is like this:
`x1 0 1 2 nan nan \n
  y1 1 2 3 5 9
`
Then pgfplots gives a warning: `Table 'transposed_line123.dat' has non-unique column name 'nan'. Only the first occurence can be accessed via column names.`
I am guessing this is a bug. It's not major, but I like my latex documents warning free :)
Any idea if this can be circumvented?

Comment: `\n` is just my way of saying there should be a new line there. If I compile the example that you include I get: `Package pgfplots Warning: Table 'transposedwithnan.dat' has non-unique column n
ame 'nan'. Only the first occurence can be accessed via column names. on input 
line 9.`

Comment: @Tohiko Yes, but it's only a warning, the plot in not influenced, see this: `\begin{filecontents*}{transposedwithnan.dat}
x1 0 1 2 nan nan 4
y1 1 2 3 5 9 10
\end{filecontents*} 
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document} 
\pgfplotstabletranspose[input colnames to={x1},colnames from={x1}]\mytabletoplot{transposedwithnan.dat} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} 
\addplot table [x=x1, y=y1] {\mytabletoplot}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}`