# Column titles as rows

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am trying to figure out a simple way to emulate a technique used in a table appearing in a [recent paper](http://ic.ese.upenn.edu/pdf/stack_ieeesp2018.pdf). Consider the following figure:

[image: Stack threat taxonomy]

What I'm specifically interested in is where they've extended the columns downwards and placed each column's description header on its own row.

### Questions

1. **Does typesetting a tabular environment like this have a name?**
2. **Is there an easy way to do this other than using (*abusing?*) numerous partial vertical lines and horizontal lines?**

For example, just the first row above "Read freed stack memory" would need to remove the zeroth and first vertical line and the second through seventh column's bottom horizontal rule. The next row would need to remove the zeroth through second vertical line and the third through seventh column's bottom horizontal rule, and so forth. A complex table with many rows and columns would quickly become difficult to produce using nothing but `\multicolumn` commands. Also note that the column titles are left justified to the zeroth column and span columns 0 and 1.

Finally, I know how to handle all of the other remaining necessities to producing this table, including rotating the row heading, adding citations, colored symbols (`X` and `R`), and justification within a single column. If you'd like to omit that from a proposed answer in order to simplify the resulting code, feel free.

### Related Questions

I've searched a few of the related topics here on TeX Exchange, and here is my reasoning why I don't think they answer the question.

- [Rotated column titles in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32683/rotated-column-titles-in-tabular): The titles still appear in the same column that they describe. In the table I've presented, the description rows transpose to columns.
- [Multirow and rotated column headers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238092/multirow-and-rotated-column-headers): Again, looking at the accepted answer's figure, the column titles still appear within the same column.
- [How to align rotated column headings in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210869/how-to-align-rotated-column-headings-in-a-table): Note how tall each of the first rows is. I'm specifically trying to avoid this phenomenon with column titles that have a lot of text.
- [Input tables as rows instead columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417582/input-tables-as-rows-instead-columns): I don't need to transpose rows as columns and vice versa.

Comment: Here's another related question. [How to format table with long column head entries?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/12979) Personally I think this approach leads to a more readable table than the image you show, which reminds me of the famous [impossible trident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_trident) optical illusion.

Comment: @AlanMunn looking at the rendered table in the accepted answer, I think that will do the trick! Bonus points because it works in Beamer too, which I hadn't considered. Please write that suggestion as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Since you haven't posted any code, I think I'll just vote to close this as a duplicate.